# Reading RAW data from a Flash POST Request ( images )

Tags: php, flash, http-post, raw-post

I'm basically interacting with a third party [API](http://www.pixlr.com/wiki/) flash file to send HTTP POST requests to my server.

I know I'm on somewhat the right path because it requires a `crossdomain.xml` file, and before I added that part nothing in the POST variables was showing up, however since I added that file there are 4 variables that are set, these POST variables are sent by the application to give me basic information about the file.. but I actually need to read the RAW POST data to actually save the image being sent by the Flash.

I'm aware there are 3 ways...

1. `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']`
2. `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA which is probably the same as the first`
3. `file_get_contents('php://input')`

For whatever reason, neither of these "work". By "work" I mean they're not being set, when I var dump them I get nothing.

Could it be that there's a setting in `php.ini` that I need to set, or perhaps the Flash application is truly not sending the actual image? I think it's doing the right thing, because it's a semi popular API and it's used by a couple other sites so I'm pretty sure it's right on their end.

And they don't require any sort of API key either.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set `always_populate_raw_post_data=1` in php.ini to use `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` ([look here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data)). Also, make sure that you set `upload_max_filesize` to a value that is large enough for your files.

However, HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA will never work if the POST data is being sent as `multipart/form-data`, which is usually used when sending files.

Unless you're sending files in a non-standard way, you really should be using `$_FILES` to retrieve the uploads. PHP automatically saves file uploads into a temporary location and places the location in the `$_FILES` variable. You can use the `move_uploaded_file` function to move it to where you want it to be. For example:

```
$place_to_put_the_file = "/my_directory/image.jpg";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
 echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
 echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

Comment: `$_FILES` was blank when I tried, perhaps I'll try all my tests again though after confirming the `php.ini` settings. Thanks.

Comment: He is asking for Flash not regular forms, it is used when a snapshot of flash made image is sent to PHP so he need to collect that first and can't use $_FILES directly , @meder : it seems that you are not getting that image from third party API so look into that And then need to edit your php.ini to receive HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA